# Bootstrap affix stop working after scroll to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, affix

I have long page with fixed left sidebar :

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1</li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
        <li>menu 4</li>
        <li>menu 5</li>
        <li>menu 6</li>
        <li>menu 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and js for `affix`:

```
$("#sidebar").affix({offset: {top: 0, bottom:420} });
```

I have and footer which is with `height:390px`.
When I first time scroll to the bottom of the page and try to scroll up the sidebar returns to its first position (to the top of the page) and it is not with `position:fixed`, anymore. It is with inline style `position:relative`, added with Bootstrap JS. When I scroll to the top I see class changed to `affix-top`. Every other scroll page position, the class is `affix`, even if it is of the bottom of the page and sidebar stay with `position:relative`.
If I use only :

```
$("#sidebar").affix({offset: {top: 0} });
```

, without `bottom`, it works fine, but I need `bottom`, because of the `footer`.

Where can be the problem ?

Comment: So many people are experiencing this issue, I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

Answer (score 8):

As the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#affix) suggest adding `position: absolute` to the `.affix-bottom` appears to solve this problem.

So you need the css:

```
#sidebar.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/TbHGEIXCk8)